# What do you call this kind of "non-homogeneous" classification task

Tags: machine-learning, classification

It's hard to search for things when you don't know the correct terminology :-(

I have been asked to look at a potential classification application where **not all of the data available is relevant to each classification, but all types of data are relevant to  classification of at least some item class**.

For example, you can imagine an archaeological digging robot that is required to classify absolutely everything it finds. "Absolutely everything" means the types of soils, clays and sands it sifts through, the different types of rocks and pebbles and pottery chips it finds, the types of fungi, bacterial and soil life it finds, as well as all the artefacts that might more directly pertain to previous human activity in the area.

So you might have DNA or other analyses that tell you whether those bones are human or animal, and which also apply to the bacteria and fungi, but simply don't apply to the sand and clay and stones. Note that data of any type will always be available for every item analysed and then classified, but will likely be some kind of noisy null value when it is not relevant to classifying an item. That is, there is no basis to classify in advance and generate relevant data selectively. So **data is generated uniformly, but with non-uniform relevance. This is what I mean by "non-homogeneous".**

If I can find out what this is called, then I might have a better chance of finding how to approach the problem and what classification techniques may be appropriate. Answers of the form "it is called X and there is a constructive discussion about it at [link]" would be fantastic :-)

Comment: I would start with the concept in databases known as EAV.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model  ... I think you're basically looking at a sparse matrix.

Comment: It seems that from the perspective of each classification task, the relevant and irrelevant features are constant. e.g. when classifying bone sources, in the example above, DNA would always be relevant. So each task can be handled as a general machine learning problem, with some of the features being irrelevant; if this understanding is correct, you could just perform feature selection for each classification task separately.

Comment: @etov - there is effectively ONE classification task only. One cannot know a priori if one is classifying bone sources. If one did, it means (part of) the classification is already done. Yes - I am talking about a system that will carry out irrelevant analyses on items, but the analysis in this application is cheap so it is all uniformly (efficiently? wastefully?) done up front. There is no basis for (further) feature selection without at least partially classifying something first - all features are relevant to at least some classification.

Comment: Did you check "Active" Learning approach? It might be a suitable option for your case.

Comment: @omatai, in that case, why not perform explicit hierarchical classification? i.e. build a first classifier to identify what is it you're classifying, then use the appropriate classifier. Trying to perform these two tasks in a single classifier, while possible, is probably not the easiest or most efficient way.

Comment: I may well perform hierarchical classification - at this stage it seems likely. But I want to be clear that the starting point is (or at least is presented as) a single classification task, and I want to know how practitioners talk about such things so I can find out what approaches they apply. I still don't have an answer for that. At this stage anyone who suggested "follow these keywords: ..."  might get a ticked answer from me!! That said, the hierarchical approach might be brittle - how do you recover from mistaking a piece of pottery or rock for a bone fragment?